# How to move ASCII characters in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a rogue-like ASCII game. I want to print `@` as the player and move it with arrows. Everything I tried was not working.

```py
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

white = (255, 255, 255) 
green = (0, 255, 0) 
blue = (0, 0, 128) 
black = (0, 0, 0)

playerposx = 356
playerposy = 254
playerpos = (playerposx, playerposy)
playervel = 16

win = pygame.display.set_mode((720,516))

pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.set_caption('Tiles')
font = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewroman", 16)
text = font.render('@', True, white, blue)
pygame.display.flip()


run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    win.blit(text, playerpos)
    pygame.display.update()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerposx -= playervel
        print("LEFT")

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerposx += playervel
        print("RIGHT")

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerposy -= playervel
        print("UP")

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerposy += playervel
        print("DOWN")

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you missed to update `playerpos`:

```py
playerpos = (playerposx, playerposy)
win.blit(text, playerpos)
```

Note, when a button is pressed then `playerposx` respectively `playerposy` is changed, but `playerpos` is never updated.

Further note, that 1 [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) is sufficient. The movement is delayed, because [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is called before [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).  The states which are returned by `pygame.key.get_pressed()` are evaluated when the events are handled by `pygame.event.get()`, so you get the states form the previous frame.

Change the main loop somehow like this:

```py
run = True
while run:

    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerposx -= playervel
        print("LEFT")
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerposx += playervel
        print("RIGHT")
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerposy -= playervel
        print("UP")
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerposy += playervel
        print("DOWN")

    playerpos = (playerposx, playerposy)

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    win.blit(text, playerpos)
    pygame.display.update()
```